# How to create a C# gui to run a simulink model?

Tags: c#, matlab, simulink, communication

I am new to Matlab and trying to code a winform based GUI for a simulink model in C#. But i had issue about how to communicate them efficiently.

1. I tried is COM communication between C# to matlab but after loading model, it was frozen.

C# code:

```
MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();
matlab.Visible = 0;
matlab.Execute("cd('path to model')");
matlab.Execute("model");
matlab.Execute("set_param('model','SimulationCommand','start')");
```

It looks like a buffer overflow to me but I couldn't find any resources on the subject.

How can i prevent freezing?

2. I tried to communicate c# and matlab to control simulink model using udp protocol. I coded a matlab script to be bridge. However, i realized that  i need to create more than one thread that will communicate with each other. Eventhough i used parellel computing toolbox in matlab, i can not accomplish it.

matlab script :

```
u = udp('', 'LocalHost', '127.0.0.1', 'LocalPort', 49013);
fopen(u);
while(true)
    command = fread(u);

   if(command == 1)
        %start model 
        set_param('model','SimulationCommand','start')
      
    elseif(command == 3)
        %pause model 
        set_param('model','SimulationCommand','pause')
    .
    .
    .
    else(command == 4)
        %stop model 
        set_param('model','SimulationCommand','pause')
    end
end
```

Is there a way  to communicate threads each other in matlab?

Any suggestion would be nice.